# is Stripe hosted invoice always publicly view-able? Is there a way to make it private?

Tags: stripe-payments

Stripe invoice hosted at **pay.stripe.com** seems to be always publicly viewable by anyone.

When I googled "pay.stripe.com", I can find and see other business's Stripe invoices as well.

Is there a way to make these Stripe hosted invoice private and viewable only by the customer and business?

Comment: Can you explain a little more about how you are seeing other business's invoices? And no, there isn't a way to password protect the invoice link, but generally you should only be sharing it with your customers anyway.

Comment: @karllekko how I googled => https://i.imgur.com/ak4gfdz.png . Results containing other business's invoices => https://i.imgur.com/O7kdDhF.png . Thanks for you comment. hmm I wonder if there would be a business side problem if the invoice is public. Some business might wanna stay super secretive to avoid copycat competitors